# How do Fair Use and Copyright laws apply to allusions in writing?

Tags: publishing, copyright, legal

I'm working on a novel where one of my main characters is young, and supposed to be obsessed with anything under the brand name "Star Wars"(Especially pertaining to the movie.) When talking with friends, they often bring up that I could get sued for using the "big brand name" in my work. I personally believe that there should be a way for me to include it in my own world building without claiming it as my own, right? One friend of mine said that he thinks it would fall under fair use, however now I'm trying to check every copyright policy under a .gov site I can get my hands on. I don't have much money, time, or experience in court, so if I want to try and put in the extra work to publish my book, I'd like to avoid any possible legal trouble WITHOUT compromising my characters if I don't have to. Anyone have any resources I can look at that pertains to my situation? It'd really help.

Comment: https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#107 lists the 4 factors that have to be considered for determining fair use. -- Anyway, considering how much Star Wars is a part of culture, and given that fans exist, I can't really imagine it's a big problem to write about them. (But obviously don't quote whole scenes.)

Comment: Consider creating a parody of SW that you can harpoon at will, and that you can re-mold to suit your themes. **Galaxy Quest** is more entertaining for its parody of Star Trek where the tropes are recognized but exaggerated and subverted. Buzz Lightyear is (was) a parody of gimmicky action figures that allowed for layered character/theme ideas…. Corporate IP fanservice (like Ready Player One and Pixels) doesn't add anything to the narrative, just a lot of dated cringe. (Hey, remember that very mainstream corporate thing…???? Whassuuuuup!!! KowaBUNGA!!! Smurfin'! Where's the BEEF? etc.)

Comment: Have a look at these answers to similar questions:  
[Referencing modern pop culture in science fiction](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/35729/referencing-modern-pop-culture-in-science-fiction/35737#35737)  

[At what point is permission needed to reference meta-characters and works in my own?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/39166/at-what-point-is-permission-needed-to-reference-meta-characters-and-works-in-my/39171#39171)  

["Too modern" words](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/37336/too-modern-words/37340#37340)